# In .net MVC with JSON, how can a serialize an integer that starts with a 0 as a decimal number

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

The default .net MVC 4 json serializer is the JavascriptSerializer class. This has worked great, but we have now realized that some customers are sending us an integer with a leading 0, this is treated as an octal number. How can we handle this?

The code is already used by a lot of people so we are not able to change the int to a string which seems to be one way to deal with this issue, but this is not an option since we believe changing the data type would break other implementations that use our code.

We have thought about changing it to use the json.net serializer, but it seems this serializer has the same issue.

e.g. 012 is converted to 10, when we pass in 012 to the int property.

Any ideas how we can fix this?

Comment: I don't know where is the serializer beeing used... I don't know if you're using web api or MVC actions. However, I can only tell you that JSON.Net allows a lot of customization, so that looks like the way to follow. JavascriptSerializer "is as is, and you can't do nothing about it"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to exactly what your problem is without seeing some code, but this is what I'm doing with decimals (user wallet/account balance part) in an application I'm currently working on.

**The Model**

```
Public Class User
    <Key>
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Phone As String
    Public Property Address As String
    Public Property City As String
    Public Property State As String
    Public Property ZipCode As String
    Public Property AccountType As Integer
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property Salt As String
    Public Property Hash As Byte()
    Public Property Company As String
    Public Property ResetPassword As Boolean
    Public Property Activated As Boolean
    Public Property Balance As Decimal
    Public Property Denied As Boolean
    Public Property DeniedReason As String
    Public Property AllowEmail As Boolean
    Public Property AllowText As Boolean
    Public Property NotifyJob As Boolean
    Public Property NotifyMessage As Boolean
End Class
```

Notice Public Property Balance as Decimal

Now, for the part where I get JSON input in a controller I made a "Helper class" for it called streamJSON that does the deserializing for me.

**The Helper Class**

```
Public Class StreamJSON
    Public Shared Function Fetch(Of Type)(ByVal SampleObject As Type) As Type
        HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Dim jsonstring As String = New IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd()
        Return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonstring, SampleObject)
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage in the controller is as follows

```
Dim postedObj = StreamJSON.Fetch(New With {.userid=0,.amounttoadd=0d})
```

this gives me a decimal value for the field "amounttoadd"

I created the helper to use anonymous objects because I got tired of creating classes for the deserializer.

Hope that helps your situation, if it did please don't forget to set my answer as the answer. thanks!